# How to use Firebase ML-Kit text recognition in java on windows

Tags: java, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition

I want to use the Firebase ML-Kit text recognition in my JavaFX application but I am not sure how to. I've used other text recognition libraries such as tesseract in Java, but the difference is phenomenal, which is why I want to use the Firebase ML-Kit's Text Recognition. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

ML Kit is only available for iOS and for Android. It is not available for Windows at the moment.

If you want to cast your vote for ML Kit being made available on Windows too, [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).